# How to implement a gateway api in spring boot grpc

Tags: spring-boot, grpc

I have a server in grpc and I can call it normally in the postman with the url

> grpc://springboot:31217

this all works but i want to create a gateway api with microservice, does anyone know how i can solve this without using http/11 and making grpc calls with spring boot or making grpc client calls without using rest? I've seen [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) but I don't know if it runs in spring boot another way is also [Running JSON to gRPC with a custom filter](https://www.springcloud.io/post/2021-12/spring-cloud-gateway-and-grpc/#google_vignette) does anyone have any better ideas?